# Removing .php extensions from sub-directory and sub-sub-directory via .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Below are the example links with current sub directories, as you can see below the htaccess code I'm using

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

currently only does the trick for - https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/page

but not with - https://www.example.com/folder1/page.php

I'm trying to get both directories to eliminate the .php extension. Any idea how to go about this, as I have no idea how to do this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you another htaccess file in the `/folder1` ?

Answer (score 0):

i think if `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` is not good function.
but you can try this

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder1/folder2/index.php?$1 [L]
```

this script will give you output like https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/your_name_url